# Insert array data values into MySQL database table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm working on huge data based project. I created arrays for every data in PHP. Now I want to insert it into MySQL database.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxxx";
$password = "xxxxx";
$db_name = "xxxxxxx";

// Create connection
$link = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);

if(!$link){
echo "Failed" .mysql_connect_error();
}

mysql_select_db($db_name);

 $data =   array (
        [1] => array(
            'eng_title' => "john",
            'content' => "john",
            'category' => "john",

        ), 
        [2] => array(
            'eng_title' => "john",
            'content' => "john",
            'category' => "john",
        ), 
        [3] => array(
            'eng_title' => "john",
            'content' => "john",
            'category' => "john",
        ), 
     );

if(is_array($data)){

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `table_a`( `eng_title`, `content`, `category`) values";

    $valuesArr = array();
    foreach($data as $row){

        $eng_title = mysql_real_escape_string( $row['eng_title'] );
        $content = mysql_real_escape_string( $row['content'] );
        $category = mysql_real_escape_string( $row['category'] );


        $valuesArr[] = "('$eng_title', '$content', '$category')";
    }

   $sql .= implode(',', $valuesArr);
    echo $sql;
    mysql_query($sql) or exit(mysql_error()); 

}

?>
```

This is the message appears when I executes the code.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

I'm using MySQLi in other programs, I think I'm using latest version of MySQL that's why the above program is not working.

Comment: Remove the ` from the $sql (can you give us what look like the $sql when you do the echo)

Comment: Insert your sql query inside your foreach.

Answer (score 0):

As i think you are missing something at "implode" . 
Try this -

```
if(is_array($data)){

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `table_a`( `eng_title`, `content`, `category`) values";

    $valuesArr = array();
    $last=count($valuesArr);
    $i=0;
    foreach($data as $row){

        $eng_title = mysql_real_escape_string( $row['eng_title'] );
        $content = mysql_real_escape_string( $row['content'] );
        $category = mysql_real_escape_string( $row['category'] );


        $sql .= "('$eng_title', '$content', '$category')";
        if($i<$last)
           $sql .=" , ";
     $i++;
    }


    echo $sql;
    mysql_query($sql) or exit(mysql_error()); 

}
```

Comment: He need " , " not spaces for inserting multiple rows

Comment: Please, remind that mysql_* function are deprecated for years.  consider using mysqli_* instead.

Comment: But in this cas, the sql statement will have " , " at the end that will cause a syntaxe error so I suggest to test if you are at the end of the array (if(sizeof(array)..) before you do $sql .= " , " to add it only if you have another value to insert

Comment: Sorry @ELOUFIRHatim , could you please revisit now ? I think it is ok now

Answer (score 0):

Use PDO it is preferable, take a look here : [Choosnig an API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

To execute insert statement with PDO you can take a look here for more example : [PDO - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

So for your case, you can do it in 2 ways :

**1. Insert a row on every loop :**

```
<?php 

$data =   array (
    1 => array(
        'eng_title' => "john",
        'content' => "john",
        'category' => "john",

    ), 
    2 => array(
        'eng_title' => "john",
        'content' => "john",
        'category' => "john",
    ), 
    3 => array(
        'eng_title' => "john",
        'content' => "john",
        'category' => "john",
    ), 
 );

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxxx";
$password = "xxxxx";
$db_name = "xxxxxxx";
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$db_name", "$username", "$password");
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $eng_title = mysql_real_escape_string( $value['eng_title'] );
    $content = mysql_real_escape_string( $value['content'] );
    $category = mysql_real_escape_string( $value['category'] );

    $query = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO table_a(eng_title, content, category) VALUES(:title, :content, :category)');
    $query->bindParam("title", $eng_title);
    $query->bindParam("content", $content);
    $query->bindParam("category", $category);
    $query->execute();
}
```

**2. Create a SQL Statement and execute it :**

```
<?php 

$data =   array (
    1 => array(
        'eng_title' => "john",
        'content' => "john",
        'category' => "john",

    ), 
    2 => array(
        'eng_title' => "john",
        'content' => "john",
        'category' => "john",
    ), 
    3 => array(
        'eng_title' => "john",
        'content' => "john",
        'category' => "john",
    ), 
 );

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxxx";
$password = "xxxxx";
$db_name = "xxxxxxx";
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$db_name", "$username", "$password");

$query = "INSERT INTO table_a(eng_title, content, category) VALUES";

$counter = 0;
$arraySize = sizeof($data);
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $eng_title = mysql_real_escape_string( $value['eng_title'] );
    $content = mysql_real_escape_string( $value['content'] );
    $category = mysql_real_escape_string( $value['category'] );

    $counter++;
    $query .= "($eng_title, $content, $category)";
    if($counter < $arraySize)
        $query .= ",";
}
$pdo->query($query);
```

Hope it will help you.